# Binding different interface methods to accept fixed but different params in implementation

Tags: java

I have few interfaces as follows: ResponseInterface, InputInterface, ClientInterface

The client interface has few methods, like so:

```
public interface ClientInterface {
    
    public ResponseInterface method1 (InputInterface in);
    public ResponseInterface method2 (InputInterface in);
}
```

In the implementation side, I have 2 different implementations of ResponseInterface and 2 implementations of InputInterface.

In the ClientImpl, I want to do something like this:

```
public class ClientImpl implments ClientInterface {
    
    @Override
    public ResponseImpl1 method1 (InputImpl1 input) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseImpl2 method2 (InputImpl2 input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But this does not work. There is no issue with specifying ResponseImpl1 and ResponseImpl2 as return types for the 2 methods but compiler will not allow setting the input types (because then these methods will not be considered as overrides of original interface methods which take InputInterface objects).

My question, how can I force the implementations of these methods to accept only certain class (that of course implements the InputInterface)?

I know how this can be done when there is only single operation in the interface:

```
public class SomeImpl implements SomeInterface <ConcreteInputClass> {
    @Override
    public SomeResponseImpl interfaceMethod(ConcreteInputClass input) {
        ...
    }
}
```

But how do I do this when interface has multiple methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This has nothing todo with the number of operations, its the Number of dynamic Class parameters

```
public interface ClientInterface<T1 extends InputInterface, T2 extends InputInterface> {

    public ResponseInterface method1 (T1 in);
    public ResponseInterface method2 (T2 in);
}
```

Then is the following ok:

```
public class ClientImpl implements ClientInterface<InputImpl1,InputImpl2> {

    @Override
    public ResponseImpl1 method1 (InputImpl1 input) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public ResponseImpl2 method2 (InputImpl2 input) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Java method calling is single dispatch, meaning only the type of the object on which the method is called determines the implementation used.

What you seem to want is called multiple dispatch (where parameter types are checked at runtime and determine the implementation), and can be simulated, e.g. with the [Visitor Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visitor_pattern#Java_example)